# Joining multiple tables yields duplicates

Tags: sql-server, select, inner-join, multiple-tables, tableadapter

In order to retrieve all Projects for a UserId, or all in case the user is admin, I want to join multiple tables. I'm using the statment in a `TableAdapter` query for MSSQL.

```
SELECT P.ID, P.CountryID, P.ProjectYear, P.Name, P.Objective, P.StartDate, P.EndDate, P.BaseCampaign, P.ManagerID, P.IsClosed, P.OrganisationUnitID, P.QualitativeZiele, P.QuantitativeZiele, 
                         P.Herausforderungen, P.Learnings, P.ObjectiveQuantitativ, P.Remarks, P.ProjectOverallID, C.Name AS CountryName, O.Name AS OEName, R.RoleName
FROM         wc_Projects AS P 
                         INNER JOIN wc_OrganisationUnit AS O ON P.OrganisationUnitID = O.ID 
                         INNER JOIN wc_Countries AS C ON P.CountryID = C.ID 
                         INNER JOIN aspnet_Roles AS R ON C.ID = R.CountryID 
                         INNER JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles AS UR ON R.RoleId = UR.RoleId
WHERE     (@ViewAll = 1) OR (UR.UserId = @UserId)
ORDER BY P.CountryID, P.OrganisationUnitID, P.ProjectYear DESC
```

In order to apply to the rather static approach for the table adapter, I start with the project.
Get all projects, resolve `CountryName` and `OEName` via FK's. Now look if you can find the role that is assoicated to the country. Then find the user that is attached to the role.
I know that this is a terrible query, but it's the only one somewhat applicable to the `WebForms  TableAdapter` way to deal with it.
When I have a `UserId` that has one or multiple roles associated with countries it works. When a admin user, that has no roles with countries associated but `ViewAll = 1` it breaks. I get constraint exceptions and the amount of results nearly tripple.
I tried rewriting the query, adding paranthesis and different joins. But none of it worked. How can I solve this?

Comment: If they're an admin, and has no roles, wouldn't no results be returned due to the `INNER JOIN` to `aspnet_Roles` failing?

Comment: They have the role of admin, just no country associated. But it's a good question since the have no `CountryID` to join. I assumed it would be bypassed by `ViewAll = 1` and didn't think of this side effect.

Comment: I can use `DISTINCT(P.ID)` to get unique values, but it is extremly slow and I don't really like it as a solution.